# Read a string with single and doubles quotes

Tags: r, string, character

Just summertime curiosity about strings in R. Let use say that I have a `x` and `y` strings. As we know we have to quote single quotes in double quotes and vice versa.

```
x <- "a string with 'single' quotes"
y <- 'another one with "double" quotes'

paste0(x, y)
[1] "a string with 'single' quotesanother one with \"double\" quotes"
cat(x, y)
a string with 'single' quotes another one with "double" quotes
```

What if we have a string with single and double quotes too? I have tried this:
Backticks do not work (R triggers an error):

```
z <- `a string with 'single' quotes and with "double" quotes`
```

Use a `\"` instead of `"` and then use `cat`:
This works well but the problem is that users must add a backslash to every double quote.

```
z1 <- "a string with 'single' quotes and with \"double\" quotes"
```

what if we have a huge **text** file (like a `.txt` for example) with both type of quotes and we want to read in R?

At this point a (silly) solution to me seems to be: work outside R, do some manipulations (like substitute all `"` with `\"`) and then read in R.
Is this a solution or does exist a better way inside R?

Here is just a little `.txt` file for example: [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tdm0thnh1rja6r4/example.txt?dl=0), anyways for who is interested, the file is just a `.txt` with one line with this text:

> a string with 'single' quotes and with \"double\" quotes

Comment: `readLines` would work similarly to tim's answer. or you could use perl and look-arounds if you are feeling particularly difficult

Comment: Perhaps the best answer is to just scrub the data before importing into R and remove the quotes.

Comment: Sorry guys for delay in adding the text file, I had problems with dropbox. Now the file should be available.

Comment: Actually, linking to Dropbox isn't great because not everyone will have it installed.

Comment: Please put a small version of the test file in the question itself rather than an external link.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it is not necessary have Dropbox installed I think. It is just an external link to a server.

Comment: @A.Webb I know that for reproducibility could be better to create a script to reproduce and download the `example.txt` file to working directory but with `download.file` I had problems to download the file that's why I decided to add the link to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may specify any alternate quoting characters as desired when reading text, e.g.

```
> p<-scan(what="character",quote="`")
1: `It is 'ambiguous' if "this is a new 'string' or "nested" in the 'first'", isn't it?`
2: 
Read 1 item
> p
[1] "It is 'ambiguous' if \"this is a new 'string' or \"nested\" in the 'first'\", isn't it?"
```

Or, just read raw text, e.g. with `readline` as suggested by @rawr

```
> readline()
 "It is 'ambiguous' if "this is a new 'string' or "nested" in the 'first'", isn't it?"
[1] "\"It is 'ambiguous' if \"this is a new 'string' or \"nested\" in the 'first'\", isn't it?\""
```